# How do I configure php.ini so I can use mail() function

Tags: email, php

So I can trying to send out emails through an automatic system but I need to set up my php.ini file to do so.  I really have no idea how to so if you could help that would be awesome!  I have to create a new php.ini file because I rent from winhost.  Let me know if you need anything and thank you so much!

UPDATED --------

I have a SMTP setup already.

Comment: on  a shared host, you should not have to set up anything. mail() should work out of the box. if not you may have to contact the host.

Comment: are you using shared hosting. is this a local machine using XAMPP?

Comment: no I buy hosting from WinHost.

Comment: we are *not* WinHost support.

Comment: @Dagon Sorry thought someone would know if I just needed to update the php.ini file.

Comment: Typically a shared host understands the requirement of their customers needing the `mail()` function to work. Perhaps this is something that WinHost can fix for you specifically.

Comment: most shared host don't even allow sites to use\update a php.ini file. but there are millions of hosts with as many variations, so you really need to work with them to sort out the issue. I note they have a support forum, searching that may well help.

Comment: Okay thanks just found it!  Thats for all the help!

Comment: Have a good one @David Biga. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server I'm getting web hosting service from (namely [MediaTemple](http://mediatemple.net/)), for example, requires the **sendmail_from** set to an existing e-mail address from that domain. So I use the following code with an address of mine in my scripts.

```
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'mail@yourdomain.com');
```

Anyway without this it wouldn't send any e-mails. Check if your issue is related to that.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I figured it out so for anyone using WinHost with same problem just use this code

```
$from = "Sender <postmaster@HostingAccountDomain.com>"; 
$to = "Recipient <user@HostingAccountDomain.com>"; 
$subject = "This is a test email sent via php"; 
$body = "This is a test email"; 
$host = "mail.HostingAccountDomain.com"; 
$username = "postmaster@HostingAccountDomain.com"; 
$password = "email_password"; 
$headers = array ('From' => $from, 
  'To' => $to, 
  'Subject' => $subject); 
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', 
  array ('host' => $host, 
  'auth' => true, 
  'username' => $username, 
  'password' => $password)); 
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
```